# Mudança de tema do alertDialog, conforme versão do Android

Tags: android, app, dialog, temas

Estou desenvolvendo um app, que utiliza alguns alertDialogs em determinados momentos. minha dúvida é a seguinte, teria como eu deixar o tema destes alerts conforme a versão do Android do smartphone que será rodado o app, ou seja, ele "pegar" as definições de customizações já do android e transmitir para o alert.
Não queria mudar através do XML e deixar um padrão, quero que o padrão seja conforme a versão do android em que o app está sendo executado. 
No caso, estou efetuando os testes através de um Moto X com Android 4.4.2 que tem o seu tema preto com azul, porém o alertDialog aparece branco com as letras pretas.

Agradeço a ajudo de todos !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context%29) o *Theme* usado pelo *AlertDialog* é determinado internamente e de forma privada pelo Android.

Se você criar um *AlertDialog* usando `AlertDialog.Builder(context)` ele será criado com o *Theme* pré definido(device default).

No entanto é possível alterar esse *Theme* usando o construtor `AlertDialog.Builder(context, theme)` onde **theme** é uma das seguintes constantes:

- THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK - Usa o theme pré definido com fundo preto.
- THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT - Usa o theme pré definido com fundo branco.
- THEME_HOLO_DARK - Usa o theme HOLO com fundo preto.
- THEME_HOLO_LIGHT - Usa o theme HOLO com fundo branco.
- THEME_TRADITIONAL - Usa o theme tradicional(pre-Holo).

Respondendo à pergunta:

Para criar um *AlertDialog* que use o *Theme* pré definido de acordo com a versão do Android use:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

Comment: Estranho, vou fazer alguns testes em outros aparelhos, porém está já `AlertDialog.Builder(context)`.
Se eu usar o theme ele ficará um padrão já para qualquer aparelho não é? 
Bom, vou ver o que consigo, obrigado !